# Javaw.exe problem with Eclipse 5.0

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, junit4, java-6

I've a problem with Javaw.exe process. I am developping an application relative to media acknowledgment using jdsk 1.6.0.11 & Eclipse 5 for Plugin Developpment. every time i want test my web cam (JUnit) then i've got a message : "Javaw.exe will close,we're sorry".Anyone can help me please??

Comment: Eclipse 5.0??? The current version of Eclipse is 3.5.1. Are you from the future?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong with so little information. Maybe your Eclipse is out of memory? Try adding something like `-Xmx1024m` in the `eclipse.ini` file in your Eclipse installation directory.

Otherwise, try installing a newer version of Java; the current version of Sun Java is 1.6.0 update 20. It's possible that you're being bitten by a bug in Java.

Which operating system are you using? Can you find any log files with error messages in your Eclipse directory?